# How to solve divs slide to the next row when setting margin, Bootstrap

Tags: html, css, django, bootstrap-5

```
{% for plant in plants %}
    {% if forloop.counter0|divisibleby:3 %}
        <div class="row row-cols-3">
    {% endif %}
    {% include 'included/_plant_cell.html' %}
    {% if forloop.counter|divisibleby:3 %}
        </div>
    {% endif %}
{% endfor %}
```

_plant_cell.html:

```
<div class="plant-cell card col-md-4 m-1">
   <div class="card-body">
      <div class="card-text">
        {{ plant.name }}
      </div>
   </div>
</div>
```

the following code results in rows that contain only two cards, and the third slides down to the next row (when margin m-1 is removed, then ok), so the general view is repeatedly: row with two cards, row with one card.

Expected to see rows with three cards in each.

Comment: By setting a margin, there is more space between the cards, so the third card no longer fits on the table, and thus is moved to the next row.

Answer (score 0):

_plant_cell.html:

```
<div class="col-md-4 p-1">
   <div class="card plant-cell">
      <div class="card-body">
          <div class="card-text">
             {{ plant.name }}
          </div>
      </div>
   </div>
</div>
```

I've changed margin to padding p-1, then separated card plant-cell from column to subsidiary div, that worked fine and as expected, also that's more normalized.